# International phone number validation using regular expression

Tags: regex, phone-number

I am validating international phone number which may have + or 0 leading with country code and space and phone number after space for this tried reglar expression with '\s' but it is failing.Why it is failing?
For eg. `+65 3333311`

Tried with below regular expression 
`^([0|\+[0-9]{1,6}[\s]?)?([0-9]{8,10})$`

Comment: The first `[` is a typo (must be removed) and note that `3333311` is made of 7 digits while `{8,10}` expects at least 8. Also, bear in mind that `[\s]` should be written as `\s`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB8vlv/1).

Comment: You should add specific error/expected value for us to see what went wrong with your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[+0](?:\d\s?){8,12}$
```

Leading + or 0 followed by 8 to 12 digits with optional separator after every digit.